# animated progress bar on btn click jquery asp.net webform

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

In the following code I have an animated progress bar that will animate as soon as document is ready.

As you can see in my jQuery, there are two commented lines, which are related to a button click.

It is working just fine with document ready but as soon as I add button click nothing happens?

What am I doing wrong?

js/jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* $("#Button1").click(function () {*/
    var progressBarDuration = 1500; // duration in milliseconds
    $("#progressbar").animate({
                    width: "100%"
                }, {
                    duration: progressBarDuration,
                    step: function (now, fx) {
                        $("#percentage").text(Math.round(now) + "%");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        // Stop the animation when it reaches 100%
                        $("#progressbar").stop();
                    }
                });
           /* })*/
        });

</script>
```

```
<button id="Button1">Start Progress</button>
<div id="progressBarContainer">
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <p id="percentage">0%</p>
</div>
```

```
<style>
#progressbar {
  height: 20px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 1s;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "really" wish the examples on the web would break down these examples and NEVER use the on document ready.

Even worse is those "attaching" some click event to a button in "on ready". Why oh why???

Software is EASY to read when you have a button, a click event for that button (and then don't have to go on some HUGE page hunt for some OTHER bit of code that MIGHT attach some event to the button). There are cases for doing this, but when not required, examples should just show a nice button, nice click event RIGHT in and for that button, and then us human beings can follow such code!!

No big deal, but these "auto magic" attaching of events to a button MUST stop, they simply result in world poverty.

I suggest you try your code this way;

```
<button type="button" class="btn"
    onclick="pbargo()">
    Start the Reactor</button>

<div id="MyBar1" style="width: 50%; height: 40px">
    <div id="MyBar1Div" style="height: 20px; background-color: skyblue; width: 0">
    </div>
    <p id="percentage">0% </p>
</div>

<script>

function pbargo() {

    var progressBarDuration = 2500;            // duration in milliseconds
    var MyBar = $('#MyBar1')
    MyBar.progressbar()                       // MUST initialize the progress bar system

    var MyBarDiv = MyBar.find('#MyBar1Div')  // get inner div always AFTER initialized
    MyBarDiv.width(0)                          // need this for run 2nd time - reset bar back to 0

    MyBarDiv.animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, {
        duration: progressBarDuration,
        step: function (pinc, fx) {
            $("#percentage").text(Math.round(pinc) + "%   --");
        },
        complete: function () {
            // Stop the animation when it reaches 100%
            // MyBarDiv.stop(); NOT required - bar stops on its own
            alert('all processing done')
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

I did include the "style" right in the div for the pbar - you can if you wish move that out to a separate style if you wish.

Note ALSO very important how I re-set the bar so if you want to run again, you can (99% of the examples DO NOT include this very important part).

Note also, I dumped the all super duper confusing use of on page ready etc. That only serves to promote world poverty.

Note how, that WHEN you look at the button, you see a nice click event. You can then go to the click event, and see/follow the code.

When you run, you get/see this:

[image]

Comment: You are most welcome. If you noted that I tend to be "un-happy" with so many examples posted? You would be correct. As I stated, I have quite a "distaste" for those document on-ready examples. They are hard to read, and don't have a very good code flow to follow. I am of the view that such coding approaches should only be used when required - not just any old time.  As per example, we never did need document "ready" to attach a click event. Anyway, this was a good question, and I plan to use the above code also!

Comment: Thats fine you dont have to explain yourself, Im not familiar with jQuery to say the least.
So having someone to guide me on how to do things well is always pleasant. thanks and have a nice day